# Traceback Error while launching 'kazam' from the terminal

Tags: python-3.x, screencast

This Traceback error is shown when `kazam` is launched from Terminal.

```
/home$ kazam
        /usr/bin/kazam:32: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
          from gi.repository import Gtk
        /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/webcam.py:24: PyGIWarning: GUdev was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('GUdev', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
          from gi.repository import GObject, GUdev
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/bin/kazam", line 147, in <module>
            from kazam.app import KazamApp
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/app.py", line 36, in <module>
            from kazam.backend.prefs import *
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/prefs.py", line 566, in <module>
            prefs = Prefs()
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/prefs.py", line 144, in __init__
            self.read_config()
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/prefs.py", line 224, in read_config
            self.audio_source = int(self.config.get("main", "audio_source"))
        TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

And Not able to open the application from the **Menu Bar**

How to **Solve** this **Trace-back error** and **restart the application?**